# Undefined index: id_order in cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea309f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When i try to go to CLINETS in BO i get error "502 Bad Gateway". All works, but only CLIENTS link not works. I tryed to clear cache folder,  besides index.php but it not helps me in php log i see this lines:

```
2021/04/13 06:17:59 [error] 1714#1714: *112 FastCGI sent in stderr: "ned index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.php on line 221
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id_order in /var/www/example.com/cache/smarty/compile/46/fa/c5/46fac58ea30739af2c0c55301ae1016a9772649f.file.list_content.tpl.ph
2021/04/13 06:17:59 [error] 1714#1714: *112 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.174.197.62, server: new.example.com, request: "GET /admin455uphrcp/index.php?controller=AdminCustomers&token=1dc27bdc261ff5a9b5178c412701cf80 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock:", host: "new.example.com", referrer: "http://new.example.com/admin455uphrcp/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=5f500f10a685e82e877221520240d38f&redirect=AdminCustomers"
```

how i can solve it? Thanks

```
PS v. 1.6.1.1
php-fpm: PHP 7.0.33-47+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:04:06) ( NTS )
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Did you enable prestashop debug mode and try to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tweak server side Nginx setting to increase header size.

Add this to your **nginx.conf** :

```
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

And / Or :

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
```

If you are using FastCGI